# How to iterate through List in a hashmap value

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap` with `String` as key and `List` as value.

Name of the `HashMap` is `pageMap`.

Say this `pageMap` has the following key and value:

```
key = order
value = [page1, page2, page3]
```

now I want to display in the following pattern:

```
order
   page1
   page2
   page3

key2
   value1
   value2
   value3
   value4
```

Please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: What did you try? and what problem are you facing?

Comment: It would be better to show some code in order to get good guidance

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class StringListMapExample {

    public static String asTreeFormattedString(HashMap<String,List<String>> map) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            builder.append(key + "\n");
            for (String string : map.get(key)) {
                builder.append("\t" + string + "\n");
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        map.put("order", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"page1", "page2", "page3"}));
        System.out.println(asTreeFormattedString(map));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is quite straightforward.

```
hashmap.get(key).iterator();
```

is an iterator for the list of the given key.

Why did you not *try* to figure it out yourself?

Comment: may be I was lazy... or trying to learn different ways to achieve a solution:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterate using iterator through all keys of hashmap using keyset()

{

  print key

  Iterate through value list using iterator

  {

   print each value

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String formatDictionary(Map<String, List<String>> map){
    String output = '';
    for (String key : map.keySet()){
        output = output + key + "\n";
        for (String value: map.get(s)){
            output = output + "\t" + value + "\n";
    return output
```

Which is pretty similar to Jeppi's answer, but using string concatenation which is one of my favorite things about Java. I haven't run any benchmarks, but my guess is that his would be a little faster, but mine would have less overhead.